# PBR shader is too transparent

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, pbr, shader-graph

I have this shader:

[image: PBR Shader Graph]

And this is the result:

[image: Result]

How can I make the grass less transparent, I swaped over from HDRP to URP and there is only PBR shader i know how to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try checking the alpha(transparency) values of the image and if it's too low then increase it, opening the image

Comment: Hi, thanks for a reply, i'm not sure how to check for that or change it. could you maby point me in the right direction.

Comment: try opening the image in visual studio(some other programs work too) then from the toolbar( [check image](https://imgur.com/a/1WbGxWj) ) unselect the buttons labelled R, G and B, leaving the button labelled A then u will find the image turned black and white, any white part is opaque, any back part is transparent and any grey part is translucent

Comment: I fixed it by linking the A channel of the Sample Texture to the Alpha instead of the RGBA, that solved it for me.